# Hydrogen atom and two-dimensional harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hydrogen

Starting from the radial one-dimensional equation for the hydrogen atom: $[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2\mu r^2}-\frac{e^2}{r}]\chi_{nl}(r)=E_{nl}\chi_{nl}(r)$ where $\mu$ is the reduced mass, I'm trying to show by setting $r=\lambda z^2/2$ and $\frac{\chi(r)}{r}=\frac{F(z)}{z}$ that $F(z)$ obeys the radial equation of the two dimensional harmonic oscillator. So far I've calculated $\frac{d^2}{dr^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda^2 z^2}(\frac{d^2}{dz^2}-\frac{1}{z}\frac{d}{dz})$ using the chain rule, but plugging this into the equation above gets me nowhere. Can anyone give me a hint on how to continue or otherwise how to get started correctly?

Comment: Not *two* such oscillators? [cf this](Cornish, F. H. J. (1984). "The hydrogen atom and the four-dimensional harmonic oscillator",  *J Phys*  **A 17** (2), 323).